# Can not launch Emulator in Android

Tags: android-emulator

I have tried to launch the emulator in Android but I am getting the dialogue box displaying.
I have tried reading all the answers related to this but I have still failed.

> emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
>   init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
>   getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
>   Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
>   emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
>   emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
>   emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
>   emulator: device fd:856
>   HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
>   emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
>   Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twzhK.png)

Comment: check out buddies answer. worked for me perfect android studio 1.5
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36478240

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478104/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator-please-ensure-intel-haxm-is-properly-installed-an)

Comment: I have the same problem.. have you solved yours? and how?