# Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am getting this error when i tired launching the emulator. Any suggestions?

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.4 < 6.0.1).
```

Comment: What is your system processor? What OS you are using?

Comment: Make sure you enabled virtualization in your BIOS.

Comment: try this answers........ http://stackoverflow.com/a/30129536/3678308

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After downloading the Intel HAXM from the android studio, you need to install it. Run the setup from Users*name*\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe
Sadly, this can be installed only on computers with Intel CPU's, so you must have an Intel to run the Android Studio emulator.

Comment: thank u .. that helped

Comment: error while intalling - This computer doesn't support intel virtualization

Comment: You must have an Intel processor. This error pops up on my computer too, since I have an AMD.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried reinstalling Intel HAXM? To do that follow these steps.

1) Open SDK Manager and Download Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) if you haven't.

2) Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory Go to extras > intel > Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the file named "intelhaxm-android.exe".

3) Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

It might take a minute or 2 to show the emulator window.

Comment: This computer doesn't support inter virtulization error

Comment: Do you have an Intel CPU? HAXM doesn't work on AMD CPUs.

Comment: yes i have intel pentium processor

Comment: Check [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237724/haxm-cannot-be-installed-in-my-laptop) to see if what was said there would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the latest version on intel haxm driver installed. You seem to have version 1.1.4 and the latest one is 6.0.1

Here is the direct link to download and install https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

enable VT-x for your system, get the latest version of haxm here https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.4.1 update and u are good to go.

(Or you can use the SDK manager to install it like the other answer suggests)

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)

or this (for Windows, see link for Mac/Linux):

Configuring VM Acceleration on Windows

Virtual machine acceleration for Windows requires the installation of the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel HAXM). The software requires an Intel CPU with Virtualization Technology (VT) support and one of the following operating systems:

Windows 7 (32/64-bit)
Windows Vista (32/64-bit)
Windows XP (32-bit only)
To install the virtualization driver:

Start the Android SDK Manager, select Extras and then select Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager.
After the download completes, execute /extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe.
Follow the on-screen instructions to complete installation.
After installation completes, confirm that the virtualization driver is operating correctly by opening a command prompt window and running the following command:
sc query intelhaxm
You should see a status message including the following information:
SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
       ...
       STATE              : 4  RUNNING
       ...

To run an x86-based emulator with VM acceleration:

If you are running the emulator from the command line, just specify an x86-based AVD:
emulator -avd 
Note: You must provide an x86-based AVD configuration name, otherwise VM acceleration will not be enabled.

If you are running the emulator from Android Studio, run your Android application with an x86-based AVD:
In Android Studio, click your Android project folder and then select Run > Edit Configurations...
In the left panel of the Run/Debug Configurations dialog, select your Android run configuration or create a new configuration.
Under the Target Device options, select the x86-based AVD you created previously.
Run your Android project using this run configuration.
You can adjust the amount of memory available to the Intel HAXM kernel extension by re-running its installer.

You can stop using the virtualization driver by uninstalling it. Re-run the installer or use the Control Panel to remove the software.