# When i run AVD in android studio following error occurred. What is the reason & solution?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.1 < 6.0.1).?

[PS  I have installed Intel 86 emulator accelerator(HAXM installer) 6.2]

Comment: If you emulate an intel cpu, you will have to install haxm in the sdk manager, either via Android Studio or via the standalone sdk manager

Comment: You need to download and install HAXM in your computer firstly then you can enable your emulator

Comment: try this link and download the haxm :-    https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows according to your android version that you are using...

Comment: Look at this question. may it help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36478322/5427149

Answer (score 0):

Install HAXM and setup as detailed in the link below:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Answer (score 0):

The Alternate Solution could be the Genymotion for personal use

https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

you can use genymotion for your emulator